# Does using a cloud database increase bandwidth

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-storage, mlab

If I'm using a cloud database like mLab or Firebase, will my application's bandwidth double?  Say a user uploads an image on the front end, that would send a post request with the image to my server, which would then send the image to the cloud based database, effectively doubling upload size. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to assume that two different databases are going to exhibit the same bandwidth consumption.  For example, Firebase client libraries don't deal with HTTP requests directly.  They also may have a local configured cache that prevents the download of data if it doesn't change.  (Also, you typically would never store images in Firebase Realtime Database.  That's what Cloud Storage is for.)

Comment: Thanks Doug. I could have been more clear with my question. I'm wondering if reading and writing to a database that's a local file on my server would reduce bandwidth by half compared to using a cloud database

Comment: My point is that it depends on how your "cloud database" does business, and how that compares to how your other solution does business.  It's a very broad topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Firebase, the idea is that your client code talks directly to the back-end services, without requiring any custom server-side code. So in your scenario of uploading an image, your client would [use the Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) to write the file directly to Cloud Storage. This means that there's only one transfer being performance, the one from the client to Cloud Storage.

If you on the other hand choose to upload from the client-side code to a custom server, and from there to Cloud Storage, you'll indeed be doubling the total bandwidth that is used.

So it's not the choice of using a cloud based data storage that determines bandwidth usage, but whether you need (or choose) to use custom server-side code that sits between the client that uploads the image, and the final destination where you want to store the image.